# return values higher than a number in prolog

Tags: prolog

with a knowledge base in this format:

```
input([[m, 0.88], 
       [h, 0.92],
       [l, 0.96],
       [m, 1.00],
       [v, 0.55],
       [v, 0.61],
       [v, 0.96]]).
```

I want to know what are the letters of elements 4 and 6 for which the numbers of 5 and 7 are grater than 0.8.

I tried running this query:

```
input(_,_,_,[X,_],[_,S],[Y,_],[_,Z]),S>0.8, Z>0.8.
```

I get the error

```
procedure input(A,B,C,D,E,F,G)' does not exist
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You have only one argument which is a list of lists - try the query:

```
?- input(X).
X = [[m, 0.88], [h, 0.92], [l, 0.96], [m, 1.0], [v, 0.55], [v, 0.61], [v, 0.96]]
```

You can already pattern match in the head by putting a list with seven elements instead of `X`:

```
?- input([A,B,C,D,E,F,G]).
A = [m, 0.88],
B = [h, 0.92],
C = [l, 0.96],
D = [m, 1.0],
E = [v, 0.55],
F = [v, 0.61],
G = [v, 0.96].
```

If you do not know which elements fulfill your requirements, you might want to use recursion with the empty list as base case and two recursive cases:

```
extract([], []).
extract([[Name,Value] | Xs], [Name| Ns]) :-
    Value > 0.8 ,
    extract(Xs, Ns).
extract([[_,Value] | Xs], Ns) :-
    Value =< 0.8 ,
    extract(Xs, Ns).
```

Then you can query:

```
extract([[m, 0.88], [h, 0.92], [l, 0.96], [m, 1.0], [v, 0.55], [v, 0.61], [v, 0.96]], Y).
Y = [m, h, l, m, v] ;
false.
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. What query do I need to get the letters from only the 5th and 7th element of the list? Also, I need to apply this function to 20 different facts in the form input(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7).  How can I do that?

Comment: Remove the outer list in the definition of input.